# Issue in creating pdf from UIView in iPad Application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, airprint

I am creating a pdf from a UIView in my iPad Application. It has size 768 * 2000. When I create pdf then it create with same size and it shows all content on one page. So I am facing problem when I print it from iPad. i am using the following code for creating pdf :-

```
-(void)drawPdf:(UIView *)previewView{   
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Waypoint Data.pdf"];
    //CGRect tempRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1068);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = [self createPDFContext:previewView.bounds path:(CFStringRef)writableDBPath];
    CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil); // 6

    //turn PDF upsidedown

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;    
    transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, previewView.bounds.size.height);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);

    //Draw view into PDF
    [previewView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; 
    CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);// 8
    CGContextRelease (pdfContext);  
}

//Create empty PDF context on iPhone for later randering in it

-(CGContextRef) createPDFContext:(CGRect)inMediaBox path:(CFStringRef) path{

    CGContextRef myOutContext = NULL;

    CFURLRef url;

    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, // 1

                                     path,

                                     kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,

                                     false);

    if (url != NULL) {

        myOutContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url,// 2

                                              &inMediaBox,                                                NULL);        
        CFRelease(url);// 3     
    }   
    return myOutContext;// 4    
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I reduce the pdf size and it has multiple page ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See example in the "Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS"

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1

Basically in the Listing 4-1 code example, they have a do while loop and take notice how it starts a new PDF page in the loop:

...

```
// Mark the beginning of a new page.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
```

...

In your current method, you only called one of the begin page methods once so that's why you'll only ever have one page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call on UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage for every new PDF page you want to create. Assuming you have a UIView of variable height, here is how you would break it down to as many PDF pages as needed during run time:

```
NSInteger pageHeight = 792; // Standard page height - adjust as needed
NSInteger pageWidth = 612; // Standard page width - adjust as needed

/* CREATE PDF */
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0,0,pageWidth,pageHeight), nil);
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
for (int page=0; pageHeight * page < theView.frame.size.height; page++)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, -pageHeight * page);
    [theView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```